# formating string value to $xx.xx format in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, c#-4.0

I have the below array which have following values {$100.0,$1000.0,$-1000.0}
i need to display values as $xxx.xx and negative numbers in brackets, so display $1000.0 as $1000.00 and $-1000.0 as $(1000.00)

Comment: "below array" --Did you forget to put it?

Comment: <LabelValues>
        <LabelValue>
          <Label>Total Tax</Label>
          <Value>$1000.0</Value>
        </LabelValue>
        <LabelValue>
          <Label>Total Payments and Credits</Label>
          <Value>$0.0</Value>
        </LabelValue>
        <LabelValue>
          <Label>Amount Due</Label>
          <Value>$1000.0</Value>
        </LabelValue>
        <LabelValue>
          <Label>Adjusted Refund</Label>
          <Value>$-1000.0</Value>
        </LabelValue>
</LabelValues>

Comment: added array in xml format

Comment: You should put that in your question. Anyway, just to clarify, do you already process this into becoming an array in C#? what is the data type of your array? `string[]`? `double[]`? You could do either a string replacement or math logic based on the data type you have...

Comment: i have a array for class LableValue which has 2 string variables, Label and Value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Since you want to add additional `0` in the `string`, then I suggest you to convert it to a `double` value first, check if the value is positive or negative, and then based on the evaluation, you decide to multiply/not to multiply by `-1` re-print it with `ToString("F2")` format.

```
string exampleStr = "$-1000.0";
double val = Convert.ToDouble(exampleStr.Substring(1));
string newStr = "$" + (val < 0 ? "(" + (val * -1).ToString("F2") + ")" : val.ToString("F2"));
```

**Original:**

For the `string` which has the positive value, you do not need to do anything. But for `string` with negative value, you could simply check for the pattern, if it `StartsWith` `$-`. If it does, you process it by replacing `$-` with `$(` and put an additional closing parentheses `)`. Something like this:

```
string exampleStr = "$-1000.0"; //this has to be replaced with your LabelValue.Value
if (exampleStr.StartsWith("$-"))
    exampleStr = string.Concat(exampleStr.Replace("$-", "$("), ")");
//resulting exampleStr = "$(1000.0)"
```

Answer (score 2):

`Parse` (to `Decimal` which is a better choice when working with money) and then *format* to requried representation:

```
  String[] source = new String[] { "$100.0", "$1000.0", "$-1000.0" };

  var result = source
    .Select(item => Decimal.Parse(item.Trim('$'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .Select(money => money < 0 
             ? String.Format("$({0:F2})", -money) 
             : String.Format("${0:F2}", money));
   //.ToArray(); // in case you want "result" being an array

  // "$100.00, $1000.00, $(1000.00)"
  Console.Write(String.Join(", ", result));
```